# .view Property of UITableViewController and UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am trying to add `UIView *separatorView` at the top of my collection views and table views which appears when the respective view's `contentOffset.y > 0`. I have made this work on my collection view by adding the view in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and added it to `self.view`. Then by using some of the scroll view delegate methods I can make it show and hide. This works well but for the table view, if I use the same concept the separatorView scrolls with the table view. I am still adding the separatorView to `self.view` but it behaves differently than on the collection view. I *don't* want the separatorView to scroll. I want it to stay at the top. Am I correct in believing that the way to make this work for the table view is to subclass `UIViewController` and manage a table view within that along with the separatorView? Is there any way to make it work in my current `UITableViewController` subclass?

Basically, why does `self.view` scroll with the table view and not with the collection view? This seems inconsistent.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Added picture to demonstrate idea.

[image]

Comment: You need to do the same thing - deal with the scroll view delegate methods and keep updating the subview's position as the table is scrolled.

Comment: @maddy In the collection view, though, I don't need to update the subview's position. I set it once when adding the view and it never moves when scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.view` in a `UITableViewController` is a `UITableView` because the tableViewController overrides `loadView` on the view controller.

If you run the following code:

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@",tableViewController.view);
```

You would get the following console output:

```
2014-05-13 21:19:02.823 Test[28681:60b] <UITableView: 0x109834200; frame = (0 20; 320 548); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x109548f00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x109548c40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

As you can see, `self.view` is not a `UIView` but instead it is the `UITableView`. Your separator view scrolls with the tableView because calling:

```
[self.view addSubview:separatorView];
```

is exactly the same as calling:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:separatorView];
```

If you wanted the separator to stay in a fixed position it would need to be added to the tableView/collectionView's superview and not the scrolling view itself.

The reason this is not happening in the `UICollectionViewController` is because `self.view` is actually a `UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView` object. This is a private class but judging by its name, I am assuming it is a `UIView` that wraps the `UICollectionView`.

The most sensible way to achieve what you want would be to use a [custom container view (child view controller)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) that would be a `UIViewController` subclass containing your separator view and tableView/collectionView controller.

If you didn't want to add a child view controller then the other alternative would be to like you said, create a `UIViewController` subclass and add your separator view and tableView as a subview within the view controllers view however if you don't use a `UITableViewController` you lose bonus functionality like automatically adjusting the tableView's contentInsets for keyboard appearance etc.

Comment: It seems odd then that I can add a subview to `self.view` in my `UICollectionViewController` and it won't scroll. It's inconsistent. I think my solution will be like I said in my question. Add table view and separator view to `UIViewController` subclass which conforms to the protocols of the table view. Thanks for your response.

Comment: i've updated my answer with a better explanation for you

Comment: Ah, thank you. Now I understand why they were behaving differently. Also, thanks for explaining why my approach isn't ideal and that I would be losing functionality.